# How do I turn off "Collected Addresses" in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

Can anyone help me figure out how to stop annoying Collected addresses?

Answer (score 4):

Go to the following menu and options setting:

> Edit/Menu → Preferences → Composition → Addressing

There you'll see a checkbox labelled:

> Automatically add outgoing e-mail addresses to my:

By default this will be set to **Collected Addresses** and you'll need to uncheck the box, then save.

Now, everytime you email, it won't store them into the catch-all area of email addresses.